# 'PDOExecption ' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000] [1044]' Accesase s denied for

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Hi i am new in PDO connection when i am useing PDO connection i got that error

> exception 'PDOExecption ' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000] [1044]'
>   Accesase s denied for user  ' '@localhost to database 
>   'dev2anal_calltrack','root,' 'in that file'

```
global $DB_HOST,$DB_NAME,$DB_USER,$DB_PASS;
$this->db = new Real_PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dev2anal_calltrack,root,");
$this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

normally root have all permission and i also check that ..

Comment: what is this "Real_PDO" thing?

Comment: oh, got it. What a funny typo %)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be:

```
$this->db = new Real_PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dev2anal_calltrack", 'root');
```

Misplaced comma.

Answer (score 1):

```
new Real_PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dev2anal_calltrack",'root');
                                          move a quote here ^
```